# Is it possible to send encrypted information that a user knows to a server without them knowing how to decrypt it?

Tags: encryption

I don't think this is possible, but I'll ask anyway. Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a HTML5 game that users play in their browser. When the game is over, they see their final score. I want to be able to send that score in an encrypted format to the server. I don't want the players to be able to reverse engineer the server call and set their score higher than what they actually earned. Is there a way to encrypt this and make it impossible for the player to reverse engineer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**: No, what you want to achieve cannot be done, but not for the reasons you think.

**Long Answer**: You can most certainly encrypt the final score and send it to your server.  You can even do this in a way that means that the user couldn't hope to decrypt it once encrypted.

The flaw lies in the fact that the user can encrypt whatever they like in the first place.  Let's say you send the encrypted score to the server in an HTTP POST request at the end of the game.  Nothing stops the user from taking apart your JS, finding the public encryption key and submitting that same POST request without ever actually playing your game.

**To actually solve your problem**: The game must be controlled on the server.  The client side of the game must simply send input actions which are then interpreted on the server.  Since the gamestate is only ever modified by the server, no fake scores can be generated.